# Handling Backslash Escaping Issue in AWS Lambda PyODBC Connection String for SQL Server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, pyodbc

In one of my AWS Lambda functions, I need to connect to an on-prem SQL Server instance and my lambda function is as follows :

```
import os
import json
import pyodbc


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Establish a connection to the SQL Server database

    connection_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=1.10.143.76;PORT=1433;DATABASE=MyDB;UID=COMPT\svcacct_clientloc;PWD=MyPassword;'

    print(connection_string)
    connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Now when I execute the code, I am getting the following error

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "('28000', \"[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'COMPT\\\\svcacct_clientloc'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect)\")",
  "errorType": "InterfaceError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 22, in lambda_handler\n    connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=1.10.143.76;PORT=1433;DATABASE=MyDB;UID=COMPT\\svcacct_clientloc;PWD=MyPassword;')\n"
  ]
}
```

Here in the error message it is showing that the username is `'COMPT\\\\svcacct_clientloc'` which is with four slashes and in the stack trace it is `'COMPT\\svcacct_clientloc'` with two slashes. I am not sure how to fix this but I have tried all the following methods.

```
server = '1.10.143.76'
database = MyDB
username = 'COMPT\svcacct_clientloc'
password = 'Password'
port=1433
driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

connectUrl = "DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};PORT={port};DATABASE={db_name};UID={username};PWD={password};".format(
    driver=driver,
    server=server,
    port=port,
    db_name=database,
    username=username,
    password=password
)
```

and also tried with `username = r'COMPT\svcacct_clientloc'` and `username = 'COMPT\svcacct_clientloc'.strip()`, but everything is giving the same error. I am running this on Python 3.8 runtime and corresponding layers has been uploaded. Also the code is working from EC 2 instance and I am able to fetch from the DB.

It would be helpful if someone can tell me how can I properly escape the username here.

Comment: Aside... `PORT` is not a connection string keyword for ODBC Driver for SQL Server. For Microsoft SQL Server the default port is 1433, so it doesn't need to be specified if your server is accessible via port 1433. If your server is listening on a different port you can specify that in the `SERVER` keyword's value by adding a comma and the port number after the server's name or address, e.g.: `SERVER=Foo,2345;` or `SERVER=192.168.1.10,3456;`

Comment: If this is a Windows login, which it looks like it is, then you can't  use usernames and passwords. Your Python needs to be logged in already as that user, and instead you use `Trusted_Connection=yes;` in the connection string.

Comment: Do you have access to the target SQL Server by way of SSMS? Can you see the SQL Error Logs node? If you look for the `Error 18456` messages (login failures) take a note of the `State` number that they report and compare them against those listed at [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error). I expect that in this case your error will list `State 6` meaning, _An attempt was made to use a Windows login name with SQL Server Authentication._

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think this uses Windows auth, but not sure and asked the DB people to confirm it as I am not able to view logs. I tried to use `Trusted_Connection=yes` , but it is showing a Keybros error.  As Lambda is serverless, I am not able to add any packages there. I have added it to the same VPC, subnet and security Group, but the error persist.

Comment: My goal is to implement an ETL job which fetch data from SQL server, transform it and load to AWS Cloudsearch. As of now I am using EC2 and this job is triggered once daily. So thought of migrating this to Lambda so I don't need to maintain the EC2 instances throughout the day. I am not dealing with much data here. You suggest any better approach for this ?

Comment: OK so it looks like you are trying to use a Windows login (rather than an SQL login). For this to work, you need to use `Trusted_Connection=yes` and you need to be joined to the domain and logged in as that user on the client machine. It is possible if difficult to do this using a Kerberos package in a docker container, but seems like that's not an option. I would suggest you just setup a normal SQL login and use that.

Comment: So essentially the whole premise of your question is wrong: you don't need to escape the backslash, becasue the whole username shouldn't have been there in the first place.